# I can't get replace to work in my javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to fetch the hash in my url so that I can use the information to set classes on different elements on my page. To do this is quite simple but I'm worried that I might be vulnerable to XSS by doing this and I want to sanitize the set variable before it can be used. The problem is that I can't get it to work.

So for example, I want to set a variable called "hash" to "gallery" from the url: www.my-domain.com/#gallery.

But I want to make sure that things like this `www.my-domain.com/#Hello<script>malicious payload</script>` won't work.

The problem is that the console reports the following:
**Hello%3Cscript%3Enasty%20payload%3C/script%3E**

I Expected to get just **Hello**. So, obviously I'm doing something wrong but I just can't figure it out.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var hash = document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1);

            hash = hash.replace(/<script[^>]*?>.*?<\/script>/gi, '').
                     replace(/<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>/gi, '').
                     replace(/<style[^>]*?>.*?<\/style>/gi, '').
                     replace(/<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>/gi, '');
            console.log(hash); //Check the result in the console
                if (hash === 'gallery' || hash === 'galleria' || hash === 'galleri') {
                    jQuery('#prod_description').removeClass('uk-active');
                    jQuery('#prod_gallery').addClass('uk-active');
                } else 
                    if (hash === 'relations') {
                    jQuery('#prod_description').removeClass('uk-active');
                    jQuery('#prod_relation').addClass('uk-active');
                } else 
                    if (hash === 'other') {
                    jQuery('#prod_description').removeClass('uk-active');
                    jQuery('#prod_other').addClass('uk-active');
                } else 
                    if (hash === 'promotion') {
                    jQuery('#prod_description').removeClass('uk-active');
                    jQuery('#prod_promotion').addClass('uk-active');                        
                }
            }
        );
    </script>
```

I have  tried things like this: .replace('l', '') and that works as expected, the first instance of 'l' in the hash is removed from the result. Which lead me to think that my regex was wrong so I tried a much simpler approach like this:  .replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '') but that doesn't work either.

Any thoughts on what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: well you did not dencode it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), just be sure not to `eval` the data; and if it gets sent server-side be sure the guys properly handle it.

You should not be doing any replacing like this as there are endless possibilities.

Ex:

```
var h = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash.substr(1));
if (h.indexOf('promotion') > -1) {
    // do some logic
}
```

Comment: I will most probably remove the replace function since it appears that it is not needed, still I want to understand this indexOf which I haven't encountered before. If I understand correctly I should use: 
if (hash.indexOf('promotion') > -1 { myLogic};, but if I want to check against multiple valid strings. In my original example I had gallery, galleri and galleria as valid string.  Is it possible to check for any of these and execute the logic or do I need to test them one by one. Also, will this approach execute the logic if the hash is: /#junkjunk<promotion>junkjunk as well?

Comment: `indexOf` looks for the specified substring within the supplied string, so assuming your hash is `junk___junk_mystring_junk**__` and you do `s.indexOf('mystring')` it will return the index at which that substring is encountered within your supplied string; or -1 if not found

Comment: Ok, but what if I have the hash Junk___gallery___junk___promotion___junk and I test this:
if (hash.indexOf('promotion') > -1 { myLogic} else if (hash.indexOf('gallery') > -1 { myLogic}; won't this mean that both logics are executed?

Comment: only the first matching one

Answer (score 2):

> but I'm worried that I might be vulnerable to XSS by doing this

You’re not - because you are not *outputting* the hash value in an HTML context anywhere.

All you are doing here, is comparing it to several different text literals. If even your `hash` variable contained something like `foo<script>malicious()</script>` - comparing `foo<script>malicious()</script>` to `gallery` is absolutely harmless, it is just a *comparison*, that will simply result in false in this case. Merely comparing strings does not execute any code.

As long as you are not inserting the value into the page somewhere, there is no XSS risk here. You can completely remove the lines where you tried to replace stuff.

Comment: I am very relieved to hear this. Thanks. The thing is that I am thinking about expanding the script so that it will compare the provided hash to all  available ID on the page. The reason is because I don't like to have to hardcode string checks like this. If I for example set the ID="TheBestID" on an element I want to make sure that my logic kicks in if #TheBestID is supplied with the URL. But as long as I don't actually put the variable "hash" as output I should be safe then I guess. Thanks again!

Comment: That is still fine, as long as you are only comparing values. XSS requires that code gets placed inside the document and gets be interpreted as HTML. So if you were to do for example something like `someElement.innerHTML = hash;`, _that_ would be a possible XSS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is encoded so you need to decode it

```
var hash = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash.substr(1));
```

Unless you put that hash directly on the page, that script tag in the hash is not going to do anything, the only thing that would happen in your string comparison is not going to do match.